# How to convert a csv to IOB format in python

Tags: python, chunking, crf

I have a csv file which I would like to convert to IOB format so that I can train it using crfsuite. I am using python and I am new to it. Here is part of the data of the csv file

[data of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMPma.png)

[this is how I want it to be..I think this is the IOB format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKSyk.png)

When I run the following code on the terminal

```
$ zcat all-data.txt.gz | ./chunking.py > all-data.crfsuite.txt
```

Error:

```
Too few fields (1) for ['w', 'pos', 'y'] ['You']
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: zcat all-data.txt.gz | ./chunking.py > all-data.crfsuite.txt

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./chunking.py", line 49, in <module>
    crfutils.main(feature_extractor, fields=fields, sep=separator)
  File "/home/dside2016/Downloads/crfsuite-master/example/crfutils.py", line 165, in main
    for X in readiter(fi, F, options.separator):
  File "/home/dside2016/Downloads/crfsuite-master/example/crfutils.py", line 70, in readiter
    'Too few fields (%d) for %r\n%s' % (len(fields), names, line))
ValueError: Too few fields (1) for ['w', 'pos', 'y']
['You']
thats the error i get

Comment: Please post text as **text**, and not as images. Now we can't copy/paste it to test it. Also post the code required to reproduce the problem. Please [edit] your question (don't add it as a comment). See: [mcve] and [ask].